# Rails nested form error: undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, nested-forms

I'm using Mongoid, awesome_nested_fields gem and rails 3.2.8.

I have the functionality working on the client (adding multiple fields), but when I try to save I get a "undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass" error.

Here is all the relevant info:

**profile.rb**

```
class Profile
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    has_many :skills, :autosave => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills, allow_destroy: true  
    attr_accessible :skills_attributes

end
```

**skill.rb**

```
class Skill
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :profile 
    field :skill_tag, :type => String
end
```

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@profile) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">

            <div class="items">
                <%= f.nested_fields_for :skills do |f| %>
                <fieldset class="item">
                    <%= f.input :skill_tag, :label => 'Skills:' %>
                    <a href="#" class="remove">Remove Skill</a>

                    <%= f.hidden_field :id %>
                    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
                </fieldset>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="add">Add Skill</a>
      </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**profiles_controller.rb**

```
  # PUT /profiles/1
  # PUT /profiles/1.json
  def update
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
        format.html { redirect_to @profile, notice: 'Profile was successfully updated.' } # Notice
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

***************** *UPDATE* ******************

I ended up switching to Ryan's nested_form gem and it works like a charm.

Comment: I think @profile is nil in update method.Please check http put request with profiles/id.

Comment: Yes, the problem is happening in the update method for sure. I'm not sure what you are asking to check for though.

Comment: Is you get params[:id] properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Your message directly points to the line of execution where it failed, ergo the line:

```
if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
```

The problem is that the `@profile` instance variable is `nil` and rails can not find the `update_attributes` method for a `nil` object.

You could easly check your server log for the `params` hash, to see what `params[:id]` (probably it isn't defined at all) by going in the terminal where you started your app.

Or you can check your development log when being in your app folder:

```
tail -n 1000 development.log | egrep params
```